# Can unlicensed users operate at a Canadian club station?

Tags: legal, canada

I am a radio amateur licenced in Canada and a member of a local club station. At a recent meeting, someone asked me whether they could operate at the station if they did not have a radio licence. I am aware that, in general, an unlicenced individual can operate an amateur station with the supervision and presence of a licenced operator, but I am not sure how this rule specifically applies to club stations.

1. Is an unlicenced individual permitted to operate radio equipment at a club station if supervised by a licenced club member?
2. Assuming that an unlicenced individual can use a club station under supervision, which callsign do they use to identify on the air - that of the club station, or that of the licenced supervisor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forwarded this question to the Radio Amateurs of Canada Regulatory Advisor and received an interpretation.

To summarize as direct responses to my original questions:

1. Yes, an unlicenced individual can use equipment at a club station if supervised by a qualified operator.
2. A non-qualified operator should use the call sign an authorized operator would use when operating the station. For a club station, this would generally be the club station call sign.

Excerpts from the interpretation (paraphrased):

---

> *Regarding the first question, about whether an unlicenced individual can operate under supervision.*
>
> The Industry Canada regulatory document RIC-3 contains the following comment:
>
> > **1.5 Non-Qualified Persons**
> >
> > Non-qualified persons may use an amateur radio station provided a qualified operator is in attendance to perform the control functions.
>
> [T]here is no distinction as to the type of station, so **this applies to 
>   clubs as well as personal stations.**

---

> *Regarding the second question, about identification.*
>
> ...I didn't find any Industry Canada guidelines. Certainly **the non-qualified operator should use the call sign an authorized operator would use when operating the station.**
>   This is usually the club station call sign when operating the club station.
>
> That is what I have seen done on field days at "Get-On-The-Air" stations,
>   at stations in museums and science centres, as well as stations operating
>   with a club or RAC call sign for contests.
>   The call sign was not changed when different radio amateurs took turns supervising.
>
> [T]he move away from licensing...to certifying radio amateurs left the status of station call signs a little more murky.
>   I am not aware of any firm rules on this so you can use common sense.
>   If your practice is for the ham operating the club station to sometimes use their own call this could be an option when a ham is supervising non-qualified operators.
>   However, **the club call sign is always correct.**

(thanks to Glenn MacDonnell VE3XRA for providing this interpretation)